# Volume appears in mtab although not mounted

Tags: mount

I have some issue with mounting:

I insert, and remove SATA card several times.
I see after removal that the mount record still exists (exists in `/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts`):
It appears as `/dev/sd*`.

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,size=248452k,nr_inodes=62113) 
devtmpfs  on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=248452k,nr_inodes=62113,mode=755) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime) 
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620) 
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=777) 
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime) 
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime) 
/dev/sda1 on /tmp type ext3 (ro,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=writeback)
```

But actually it is **not really mounted** - on doing `ls /path` I don't see the files:

```
ls /tmp
EXT3-fs error (device sdb1): ext3_readdir: directory #2 contains a hole at  offset 0
```

Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Comment: Have you removed by7 safely unmounting ? May be a process is still using that `dangling` location. Try **fuser** command, who is using that partition.

Comment: Hi, I did not unmount it safetly , I just removed the media physically